# AngularJS ng-click not working in IE11

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

I have the following button defined in HTML:
`<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="onCancel()">Cancel</button>`
with a corresponding function attached to $scope in the controller.

I'm using AngularJS 1.2.21.

When I click the button in Internet Explorer 11 nothing happens - that is, `ng-click` does not fire.

Comment: Why do you need `type="button"` attribute?

Comment: @miensol: Because I don't want it to be a "submit" button, and I prefer to be explicit (as opposed to simply leaving off the `type=""` attribute).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I added a `value="cancel"` to the `<button>` element to end up with:
`<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="onCancel()" value="cancel">Cancel</button>`

Now `ng-click` fires in IE.

Comment: As an aside, I was inspired to take this approach by a comment at http://henriquat.re/appendix/angularjs-and-ie8/necessary-changes-for-ie8-compatibility.html about `<a>` tags needing to contain a valid `href`.